# Ubuntu 18.04 gdm3 starts two X servers and it leads to high CPU usage

Tags: 18.04, xserver, cpu-load

CPU usage after login in ubuntu 18.04 is very high, the reason, as i can see, gdm3 starts two X servers for some reason, if i switch to lightdm this doesn't happen, but then i got problem with gnome screen lock, and anyway i want to use gdm3. So, is there any way to prevent gdm3 from starting 2 X servers? For now i'm just killing the first one (with smaller PID), but i want a better solution, obviously.